# Sockets and Future Functions in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

1. Summarize the Problem.

I am trying to write an async function that returns data when a receive is completed from a socket. I am having trouble returning the correct data from my async function. The error I am receiving is that the `rtn` variable is not set and can be null.

2. Describe what you've tried.

I've tried writing the async function but haven't been getting the desired result. I tried using the late keyword for the variable `rtn` but that resulted in a runtime exception that the variable was null.

3. Show some code.

Below, is the function giving me problems. Any advice or resources would be welcomed. I tried going over the Flutter documentation for async but it wasn't too helpful for me.

What I want is that the network data is returned from this async function.

```
Future<int> fetchNumVideos() async {

    int rtn;

    Socket.connect(baseStationAddresses[0],
        baseStationPort, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5)).then((socket) =>
    {
      socket.listen((data) {
        String socketData = String.fromCharCodes(data);

        print("socketData: $socketData");

         rtn = int.parse(socketData);

      },
        onDone: ((){
          socket.destroy();
        })
      ),
    }).catchError((onError) {
      rtn = 0;
    });

    return rtn;
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: replace `int rtn;` with `Completer<int>` class and instead of `rtn = int.parse(socketData);` call `completer.complete(int.parse(socketData));` and instead of `return rtn;` call `return completer.future;`

Comment: @pskink I did not know of this class prior to your comment. Thank you! I added an answer with the working solution.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: btw, instead that lengthy code, why not to: `socket = await Socket.connect(...); data = await socket.first; returrn int.parse(data);` ? or something like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved by pskink's comment.

The solution was to use the [Completer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) class.

```
  Future<int> fetchNumVideos() async {

    final completer = Completer<int>();

    Socket.connect(baseStationAddresses[0],
        baseStationPort, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5)).then((socket) =>
    {

      socket.listen((data) {
        String socketData = String.fromCharCodes(data);

        print("socketData: $socketData");

         completer.complete(int.parse(socketData));

      },
        onDone: ((){
          socket.destroy();
        })
      ),
    }).catchError((onError) {
      completer.complete(0);
    });

    return completer.future;
  }
```